# Filter Fluxor-state in Blazor

Tags: blazor, state-management, fluxor

I use Fluxor for the client-side state management of a wasm app. The basics work just fine, and I am able to get a list of data objects from my database and I can mutate these via actions.

However, I'd like to filter the data stream with input form the component UI, e.g. from a dropdown list a user selects. Something like `Show only records from user x`. Where x is a value from the dropdown the user has selected.

Now I was thinking about making this an action as well: `new ChooseFilterValue("x")`

Coming from an Angular/NGRX background, I was hoping to create a selector which filters the state according to the other state (state composition) and I can then subscribe to the result in the UI. Unfortunately, there in Fluxor there is no such concept of a selector.

But maybe I am thinking this too difficult. How would you solve this problem? Any help and/or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if its elegant but I just created a public method on Fluxor's state object with a parameter I populate from a UI element (dropdown or chipset). The method than filters the state. It's everything I need and works.

Comment: Does this work for you? The absence of selectors in Fluxor also surprised me. But this is by design. The workaround above, for me, works with inputs that are data-bound and therefore is sufficiently reactive for me